# Integration of Oracle Database in a Rails Application

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, oracle

I have a Rails Application and I have an SQL Database. I am using Oracle SQL Developer to manage it. My question is how do integrate these two together so that I can display the database data?

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously a big subject, but the major steps I can think of are:

1. For each table in the database that you want to include in the Rail App, you define a model class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base
2. If the database does not respect Rails conventions with regard to naming you will have to provide class methods in each model to define the primary key column and the table name.
3. You create associations in the models to describe the joins between the tables.